# Send data from servlet to jsp not working

Tags: jsp, servlets

Funny as it may seem, I have tried virtually every solution online,but still no valid solution, I can't print data from a servlet to a jsp page in java,below is my code

Servlet Code...Student.java

```
String name = "Chrisgeek";
request.setAttribute("student_name", name);

RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/students.jsp"); 
rd.forward(request, response);
```

student.jsp

```
       <%
            String text = (String)request.getAttribute("student_name");
            out.println(text);
        %>
```

Comment: I don't understand @Arvind

Comment: Am using netbeans, how then do i specify which to execute first?

Comment: Right clicking on Student.java > Run

Comment: Still no progress.

Comment: please post all your servlet code. What is the url mapping of the servlet also?

Comment: are you able to just do `${student_name}` anywhere inside the html? Not in a scriptlet!

Comment: I was supposed to run the servlet and not the jsp file,it's all good now.